# Hiding Directory Browsing in Linux

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

I am trying to turn off the web directory browsing, like if somebody goes to a page where index.html or index.php doesn't exist, then it brings up a list of directories. I found [this page](http://www.camelrichard.org/topics/Apache/Turn_Off_Directory_Browsing) that looked like it had the answer. It told me to add a "-" in front of the indexes so that his httpd.conf file went from:

```
<Directory "/u01/app/apache/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory "/u01/app/apache/htdocs">
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

So mine looks like this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks Includes Indexes MultiViews All
    Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
</Directory>
```

And I tried doing the same thing: adding a "-" in front of "indexes":

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks Includes -Indexes MultiViews All
    Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
</Directory>
```

But it hasn't made any effect after I restarted apache, do I need to take out "All" or something? Any advice would help, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You guessed it: the word `All` in `Options` is undoing you here.  Drop that and you'll be all set.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Not sure why that was set, perhaps it was due to a codeigniter installation, everything seems to be working without though

Comment: You can also, for what it's worth, just move `All` to the front of the list (i.e. do something like `All -Indexes`).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the word Indexes and restart Apache that should fix it. Also you have the

```
AllowOverride All
```

in your config which would still allow anyone who specified the Indexes option in htdocs to enable directory listing.